# Manage and Publish ArcGIS Server v10.8 Services using API with no AGOL and no Portal

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-server, arcgis-python-api

I have ArcGIS StageServer with Site1 and multiple Map\GeoCode\Routing Services.
There is no WebAdapter, ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Portal installed.
We need to update multiple Production ArcGIS Servers from StageServer.

I'm trying to find a way to manage and streamline publishing\updating ArcGIS Server Map, GeoCode and Routing Services.
StageServer has updates to one of the services

1. Set Map1Server.site_1 to maintenance mode
2. Publish\Update service from StageServer.site1 to Map1Server.site1
3. Set Map1Server.site_1 to available mode

A. I found that ArcPy doesn't have capabilities to manage\set site modes

B. I tried to use ArcGIS Python API, however, it looks like it requires either ArcGISOnline, Portal or WebAdapter.

What would be the best approach here?
I think we can install WebAdapter, but I'm trying to find the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: While it is possible to rewrite the relevant parts of the  Python API in pure Python, I'd suggest that installing a WebAdapter is a much less onerous task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a toolkit that predates portal and AGOL.

Check this link: https://hub.arcgis.com/content/12dde73e0e784e47818162b4d41ee340/about

I needed automation before any of the new python apis were around, and I used this toolkit. It is python based and there are libraries, so make sure that you get everything into the python folder that you work from but this should help you out (without the web adaptor).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a great example which I can use.
Appreciate it.